# javascript new date working in chrome but not in firefox

Tags: javascript

I am trying to get a value of date from a hidden field and converting into proper date format in javascript . The system works but only in chrome . My code is

```
        var futureDate  = new Date($(".camp_end_date").val());
        //alert(futureDate);
```

the hidden field value is

```
2014-06-02 00:00:00
```

when i alert this on chrome it outputs `Mon Jun 02 2014 00:00:00 GMT+0530(India Standard Time)` but in chrome and all other browsers it outputs `invalid date`.

Comment: Date handling is currently not straightforward in JS. I recommend to use a library like http://momentjs.com/.

Comment: @FelixKling: momentjs is terrible! why did they had to invent yet another date format syntax? aren't there enough already?

Comment: works here (opera): `Mon Jun 02 2014 00:00:00 GMT+0200`. What other browsers did you try?

Comment: @njzk2: I really doubt that moment.js introduces a new *date format*. But it lets handle all kind of data formats, unlike JS native `Date` constructor, which is an advantage.

Comment: @FelixKling: a new date formatting *syntax*. yes, they do.

Comment: @FelixKling: specifically, d/D/DDD are incompatible with ICU format, while most of the rest is.

Comment: @njzk2: I see. Which library would you recommend instead then?

Comment: @FelixKling: I have no idea. So far I have not found anything satisfactory. I just stumbled upon https://github.com/twitter/twitter-cldr-js but have not tested it yet. (moment js did seem quite promising until the `D` line, which I require. There are also addons to translate other formats into momentjs format).

Comment: @njzk2: I mean, it always depends on the context anyway. There is nothing wrong with moment.js if you don't have to share date format syntaxes between platforms/systems/etc. Anyways afaik, date support should become better in ES7 or after (so maybe in 6 years or so :P ).

Comment: @FelixKling: plus, there are like thousands of formats (php as one, ICU defines one, apparently CLDR is slightly different...), and the momentjs lib seems quite complete and simple to use. Just a pitty that it is close but not exactly compatible with some other formats.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This happens because your date is neither valid RFC2822 nor valid ISO 8601, which are the formats supported by [dateString constructor in Date object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date). For some reason Chrome seems to accept a wider range of formats, including yours, which is not strictly valid ISO 8601 date. Valid date would be:

```
2014-06-02T00:00:00
```

The simplest fix I can think of is to replace the space with a `T` before feeding it to Date constructor:

```
var futureDate = new Date($(".camp_end_date").val().replace(" ", "T"));
```

Comment: Boi . . You are a super genius . Thanks bud

Comment: using this there is a difference in time in Mozilla and chrome

Comment: My guess is that your browsers may assume different time zones. What happens if you add `Z` to the end of the string?